# MYSQL varchar to date

Tags: mysql, date, type-conversion, varchar

I'm having some trouble when converting one column to date.

I want this `'01/02/98'(day, month, year)` to convert to `'1998-02-01'(year, month, day)`.

And also how you convert `'98'` to `1998`.

Comment: In your case (spanish format), you will need to use: `STR_TO_DATE("01/02/98", "%d/%m/%y")`. Reference here: [STR_TO_DATE](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_str_to_date.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want this '01/02/98'(day, month, year) to convert to
>   '1998-02-01'(year, month, day). And also how you convert '98' to 1998.

`STR_TO_DATE()` handles both cases.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

The formats are explained here https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

%e matches day of the month, numeric (0..31) 
%m matches month, numeric (00..12) 
%y matches year, numeric (two digits)

**Query**

```
select str_to_date('01/02/98', '%e/%m/%y');
```

**Result**

```
| str_to_date('01/02/98', '%e/%m/%y') |
| ----------------------------------- |
| 1998-02-01                          |
```

[demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mwj9S5dkypmsbLngjsc1vu/0)

Comment: Thank youuuu!! I was getting stressed, I've tried that function but my second parameter was wrong.

Comment: @MDTeach when an answer has helped you, you should consider marking it as accepted answer (green tick). Please see: [How to accept an answer for closure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). +1